# Identifying Lego set from 1980's

Tags: set-identification

[image: Mini Figures, windows, doors, fence and roof pieces]

Can someone please help me identify this Lego set from the 1980's?

I remember building a house, work shed/garage and some type of vehicle. The base plate is light gray. It came with 2 minifigures, male and female, a broom and shovel, and slanted windows that were used for a skylight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My closest bet would be the [Car Repair Shop](http://brickset.com/sets/1966-1/Car-Repair-Shop). However, there are lots of other sets that could match the description.

Edit #1:

The other potential candidates:

- [Weekend Home](http://brickset.com/sets/6370-1/Weekend-Home)
- [Auto Workshop](http://brickset.com/sets/6369-1/Auto-Workshop)
- [Holiday Home](http://brickset.com/sets/6374-1/Holiday-Home)
- [Houses](http://brickset.com/sets/1484-1/Houses)
- [House with Roof Windows](http://brickset.com/sets/1854-1/House-with-Roof-Windows)
- [Holiday Villa](http://brickset.com/sets/6349-1/Holiday-Villa)

In case none on these is what you are looking for, you could take a look at [Bricklink](http://brickset.com/sets/theme-Town/page-1) and browse the results.

Edit #2:

Based on the picture you added, the [730-2 BASIC Building Set](http://brickset.com/sets/730-2/Basic-Building-Set-7) seems the most likely choice (it has both minifigs, the broom, the shovel, the faucet, the slanted windows). There are also many pieces from other sets: both the blue and the red-yellow propeller, the yellow spaceship engine besides the male figure, etc.

Comment: Funny - bricklink doesn't show the faucet as belong to any other set than [a few airplane sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=69c03&in=S) - it was the component I went to search for and it didn't find the 730-2 set.

Comment: Yes, I found that Brickset doesnt show it too, that's why I turned to Peeron, where I found this set.

Comment: Figured it out - the same tap has 2 entries in Bricklink, [here](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=69c01&in=S) is the other one. 69c01 is the old 'light gray' and 69c03 is the new 'light bluish gray', hence the difference